# Mandrill email not send from local app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, mandrill

I have configured my local environment as like this

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: ENV["DOMAIN_NAME"],
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: "username",
  password: "api key
}
```

When I send email from my app I got this error

`Net::SMTPServerBusy in MailsController#import`
 `401 Syntax: HELO hostname`

when I change config from `mandrill` to `gmail`, I can send email from my app. I dont know what's wrong.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does it work in `production`?

Comment: yeah it's working fine in production. But not development.

Answer (score 0):

This is not only related to Ruby.

On this document:
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

We can find a param "hostname" with some documentation:

> In case the hostname of the SMTP client is not properly configured,
>   e.g. if the client hostname is not fully qualified, certain SMTP
>   servers may reject the HELO/EHLO commands sent by the client. To
>   overcome this issue, you may set the value of the localhost property
>   to the fully qualified name of the client host. See also the
>   "mail.smtp.localhost" property in the documentation for the
>   com.sun.mail.smtp package.

So according to the packjage doc, if you are on the Java world you could use this option `-Dmail.smtp.localhost=someHostName`

> Local host name used in the SMTP HELO or EHLO command. Defaults to
>   InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(). Should not normally need to
>   be set if your JDK and your name service are configured properly.

So I guess there may be something wrong configured in your OS and your Ruby client can't get a proper [Fully Qualified Domain Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name).

One teammate had this problem on its MacOS laptop. She used the Java option so I can't tell you more :)